# android update luanching from app store

Tags: android, updates

I Have Some Android Application On Google Play Store Of Version GingerBread.Many Users Install the app from Store .Problem Is that Now i have Some Updates in My apps and I can't afford to upload new one and again ask users to uninstall the old one and install the new one.I want to show some notification on running app that user should asked to update the new version or not.Please Help Me to find out this solution and How can be this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything for this. Just upload you new app with greater versionCode in the manifest with same key and package names. Google Play automatically does your job.

Comment: But Sir I Observed the Google Play don't upload the application with same pkg name.How can be this managed

Comment: It does allow if you are using same key

Comment: Don't forget to upload it as the same app

Comment: Don't try to upload it as some different app. Just open the previous one and upload apk with higher versionCode.

Comment: It automatically recognizes that your app is the update of the previous one

Comment: Sir Wil U Please Tell me How Much time It Takes to Update after uploading New apk file On Google Play

Comment: I am not sure that every app takes same time

Comment: yes its updated now thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

For update package name, release certificate should be the same, version shoul

Comment: Sir Wil U Please Tell me How Much time It Takes to Update after uploading New apk file On Google Play